# Link2SD | 1st partition not working / not showing / not detected

Tags: android

My problem is, that I can't see the 1st. `partition` in the `storage informations`.

Hardware:

- Sony Android mobile phone (don't know exactly the model; is my girlfriends)
- Android 4.2.2
- Samsung PRO Plus Micro SDHC 32GB (https://www.amazon.de/Samsung-Micro-100MB-Speicherkarte-Adapter/dp/B06XFRZ9Z6)

I have prepared my mobile phone with the following tutorial:

- https://www.wikihow.tech/Use-Link2SD

After starting the app (Link2SD) I could successfully create the mount script! But wenn entering the `storage informations`, the 1st. partition is not beeing detected properly.

On the picture below, you can see **Ext. Speicher SD /storage/sdcard1**.

[image: preview]

I have partitioned the SD card **50:50**, so each partition has got ~16GB.
When plugin the mobile phone to a windows PC, I can only see the **sdcard0** with 4GB and not my 16GB storage. Also in the Settings/Storage the SD-Card is not properly detected.

Comment: I remember vaguely from a post at xda that you should not make the secondary partition more than 1 GB. Thats what causing the problem, also link2sd wont detect a partition that big and do provide the PARTITION FORMAT.

Comment: So you mean, I should make partition1 - Fat32 - 31GB and partition2 - ext2/3/4 - 1GB ?

Comment: Also I would strongly recommend that you flash a custom ROM so that the partition and space wont be an issue. Starting from android Marshmallow you wont face the SPACE issue cuz it will auto format the SDCARD and integrate the memory as internal.